# Why am i having AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'answer' on django serializer "PUT" method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the nested serializer in it but, it saying queryset has no attribute, below is my code:

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response        
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view       
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception  
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\quiz\views.py", line 39, in put
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\quiz\serializers.py", line 47, in update
    answer = instance.answer.all()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'answer'
[12/Jun/2022 19:13:39] "PUT /quiz/q/django/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 108967
```

**Views.py**

```
class QuizQuestionDetail(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        quizz = Question.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(quizz, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        quizz = Question.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(quizz, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        
        model = Answer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'answer_text',
            'is_right',
        ]

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    answer = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id','quiz', 'title','answer', ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        answers_data = validated_data.pop('answer')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for answer_data in answers_data:
            Answer.objects.create(question=question, **answer_data)
        return question

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        answers_data = validated_data.pop('answer')
        answer = instance.answer.all()
        answers = list(answer)
        instance.quiz = validated_data.get('quiz', instance.quiz)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.save()

        for answer_data in answers_data:
            answer = answers.objects.get(pk=answer_data['id'])
            answer.answer_text = answer_data.get('answer_text', answer.answer_text)
            answer.is_right = answer_data.get('is_right', answer.is_right)
            answer.save()
        return instance
```

**Model**

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

class Quizzes(models.Model):

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Quiz")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Quizzes")
    ordering = ['id']

title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=_(
    "New Quiz"), verbose_name=_("Quiz Title"))
category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

class Updated(models.Model):

```
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name=_("Last Updated"), auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

class Question(Updated):

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Question")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Questions")
    ordering = ['id']

SCALE = (
    (0, _('Fundamental')),
    (1, _('Beginner')),
    (2, _('Intermediate')),
    (3, _('Advanced')),
    (4, _('Expert'))
)

TYPE = (
    (0, _('Multiple Choice')),
)

quiz = models.ForeignKey(
    Quizzes, related_name='question', on_delete=models.CASCADE  , null=True, blank=True)
technique = models.IntegerField(
    choices=TYPE, default=0, verbose_name=_("Type of Question"))
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Title"))
difficulty = models.IntegerField(
    choices=SCALE, default=0, verbose_name=_("Difficulty"))
date_created = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Date Created"))
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    default=False, verbose_name=_("Active Status"))

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

class Answer(Updated):

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Answer")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Answers")
    ordering = ['id']

question = models.ForeignKey(
    Question, related_name='answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE  )
answer_text = models.CharField(
    max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Answer Text"))
is_right = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.answer_text
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Can you add the code for the models here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, drf can't update list of objects only one object at a time
so instead of filter use get_object_or_404
so this line `quizz = Question.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])` should be this `get_object_or_404(Question, pk=kwargs['pk'])` 
remove this line `answers = list(answer)` it will cause evaluating the queryset, you don't need that anyway 
for this line `answer = answers.objects.get(pk=answer_data['id'])`
replace answers with Answer that's your database model name 
one more thing to make your code faster, for the update replace the forloop with bulk_update instead of calling your database in every loop

Comment: I got this message                                        Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.

Comment: Is still showing the same error, should I send you the full source code

Comment: which error is showing now? queryset has no attribute answer or list update?, use get so it return a single object method and remove the many=True and it should work

Comment: File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\roy\project\HelpMe\sunny\backend\quiz\serializers.py", line 56, in update
    answer = answers.objects.get(pk=answer_data['id'])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: answers is a list, to use objects you need a django model object not a queryset not a list just a single object so replace answers with the actual model name or remove the objects word
Remove the ```answers = list(answer)```

Comment: in update
    answer = answers.objects.get(pk=answer_data['id'])
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: again
> to use objects you need a django model object not a queryset not a list just a single object so replace answers with the actual model name

Comment: Is creating new object in the array, is not updating it .